# datagridview cells multiplying and sum the column in textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum, row

I have a problem in  multiplying  tow cell of one row and sum one of the column after multiplying in datagridview and show the final result in textbox in C# , please guide me how can I do this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHI6P.png)

```
  private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            int multiplication  = 0;           
            int sum  = 0;
         
            for (int i = 0; i < saleDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (saleDataGridView != null)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out sum) && int.TryParse(saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(), out multiplication))
                    {
                        int total = sum * multiplication + Convert.ToInt32(saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);



                        // sum += *Convert.ToInt32(saleDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);



                        txttotal.Text = total.ToString();
                    }
                    else {

                        MessageBox.Show("error");

                    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9j5u.png)

Comment: are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: i am using winforms

Comment: can you explain your question in detail

Comment: i have tow column in my saledatagridview one quantity and another is price i wnat to multiple quantity and price column in each row afther multiplying i want to sum price column and show the result in textbox by button click.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways you can approach this. Obviously you can loop through the grid rows and calculate the total for each row and sum all those values. Or if the grid has a data source, you could loop through those rows/items and get the totals also.

Therefore, since you do not say if the grid has a data source or not, this makes things difficult to suggest a proper solution. Example, if the grid’s underlying data source is a `DataTable`, then, you could “add” a “Total” “Expression” column to the grid that would calculate the “Price” * “Quantity” value for each row. This would remove one calculation from your code. You could also set the text boxes text to the SUM of all “Total” cells in the `DataTable` with the `DataTable`’s `Compute` function, thus eliminating another calculation you have to code. Any time the grids “Price” or “Quantity” value changes, then, we would update the text box sum total using the data tables `Compute` function.

Or as Mansur’s answer suggest, you could create a simple class to manage both the grid’s data source in addition to the text boxes data binding. This is the approach used below. In the `Item` class there would be three properties where “Price” and “Quantity” are both “editable” properties. The third property will be a read only “Total” that will return the “Price” * “Quantity” value.

We could simply make a list of `Item` objects and it should make things easier, however, I say let’s go one step further and create another Class called `ListOfItems` it will have two properties. A `BindingList` of `Item` objects AND a `decimal` read only property that returns the `SumTotal` of ALL the items in the list.

The idea with this class is that we can now bind BOTH the grid AND the `TextBox` to the “same” `DataSource`. The grid’s `DataMember` would be the `BindingList` of `Item` objects, and to bind the `TextBox` we will set its `DataMember` to the `SumTotal` property. This should make things much easier as far as calculating each rows total and the total of all rows.

```
public class Item {
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public decimal Total => Price * Quantity;
}


public class ListOfItems {
  public BindingList<Item> Items { get; set; }

  public ListOfItems() {
    Items = new BindingList<Item>();
  }

  public decimal SumTotal => Items.Sum(x => x.Total);
}
```

However, there is one small issue. If we look at the `ListOfItems` Class… we can see that `SumTotal` will reflect the current state of `Items` List, however if the list changes, then we will still need some mechanism to signal to the text box to “update” the total. In addition, when the grid cell values are changed by the user, there are certain situations where the data in the grid, may not necessarily exist in the underlying data source. In that case the total could be wrong.

These issues (among others) could be resolved if we simply use a `BindingSource`. If we use a `BindingSource` and set it’s `DataSource` to our `ListOfItems` object, then all we need to do when a cells price or quantity changes is to call the `BindingSource`’s `ResetBinding` method and it should update the grid and text box in one step. Even if this was not needed, using a `BindingSource` in a grid has numerous advantages… like this.

To give this a test, you can create a new winforms solution, and drop a `DataGridView` along with a `TextBox` for the sum total onto the form. There are two global variables… the `BindingSource` and the `ListOfItems` object. The code below is to generate some test data.

[image]

```
private ListOfItems GetData() {
  ListOfItems listOfItems = new ListOfItems();
  listOfItems.Items.Add(new Item { Price = 10.50m, Quantity = 2 });
  listOfItems.Items.Add(new Item { Price = 1.0m, Quantity = 3 });
  listOfItems.Items.Add(new Item { Price = 1.50m, Quantity = 3 });
  return listOfItems;
}
```

The load method to set up everything…

```
BindingSource bs;
ListOfItems AllItems;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  AllItems = GetData();
  bs = new BindingSource();
  bs.DataSource = AllItems;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
  dataGridView1.DataMember = "Items";
  textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "SumTotal");
}
```

Finally, the grids `CellValueChanged` event to update the text box when a “Price” or “Quantity” cell changes. All we need to do is Reset the binding source for the text box to update.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Price" ||
      dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Quantity") {
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Price"].Value != null &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Quantity"].Value != null) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Price"].FormattedValue.ToString()) &&
          !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Quantity"].FormattedValue.ToString())) {
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, as suggested earlier, you could do the same thing using a `DataTable`, by changing the `Items` property of `ListOfItems` class to a `DataTable` and either use LINQ or the `DataTable`’s `Compute` function to compute the sum total. In my tests, this will require and extra step, however it is trivial.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy by using Binding DataGridView using generic List.

For example

```
class MyModel
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Binding this model to DataGridView and calculating totals using LINQ, after click button example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<MyModel> myData;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myData = new List<MyModel>() { new MyModel() {Price=35000,Quantity=100 }, new MyModel() { Price = 150000, Quantity = 322 } };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myData;
        }        

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = myData.Sum(s => s.Price * s.Quantity);
            txtBoxTotal.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

other solution, if you want calculate by using DataGridView Cells:

```
double result = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

 var price = double.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
 var quantity = double.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
 result += price * quantity;
}
txtBoxTotal.Text = result.ToString();
```

For your case:

```
private void btnsum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var result = 0;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in saleDataGridView.Rows)
    {
       int price, quantity;
       if (int.TryParse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out price) && int.TryParse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), out quantity))
          result += price * quantity;
             else
                  MessageBox.Show("error");
      }
 txttotal.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {      
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    }
    txtTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).